# How to read information from Microsoft Project Standard 2013 Programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, ms-office, ms-project

I am a new programmer and I have been attempting to find information regarding Microsoft Project Standard's (or Microsoft Project Professional) API in order to access data from a .mpp file in order to perform some calculations in another program. So far I have found information about how to use "Microsoft Project Server 2013" as a way to programmatically access information, but I wish to not to use microsoft project server to do this task. Instead, I will only want to read a regular .mpp file on Visual Studio 2013 using c#. So far I have only found an example using .NET Interop, but I would like to this without interops. In order to get started, I would like to do the following tasks:

•   Open Project File (.mpp)
•   Read Inputs from table
•   Output the data read into a CSV file

I am just looking for a concrete example of some code to do this tasks in order to help me get started.

I will appreciate any help that anyone can provide.

Comment: In order to read an mpp file with c# you need to use the interop. The binary specification for the mpp files is not published by Microsoft.

Comment: Hi Rachel, thanks for your response. Could you provide an example of how to do the following functionality specified above?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read data from an MPP file without using Interop, you could try [MPXJ](http://mpxj.sf.net). It's available from NuGet if you are working in Visual Studio.

Comment: Ah! I did not know MPXJ could be used from .Net. I look forward to trying it out.